# Как прописать ссылку в wordpress с плагином PODS

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Как прописать ссылку на php? Как вставить изображение разобрался, но найти как вставить ссылку так и не понял. Внизу картинки есть ссылка, которая в плагине PODS создавалась через "Сайты", но как ее сейчас вставить в код html с помощью php?
Картинку вставлял вот так: `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>`
Предпологаю что и ссылку можно вставить почти так же, но как не знаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через [get_post_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_meta)

Comment: Не работает, после такого ввода у меня все пропадает, ввожу вот так                                                     `<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(); ?>" >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно предположить что таким образом:

```
<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'link', true ) ); ?>
```

конечно же если ярлык Вашего поля `link`.

Либо воспользоваться [PODS display](https://pods.io/docs/code/pods/display/).

```
<?php   
$your_post_type_name = pods('your_post_type_name', get_the_ID()); // Либо $post->ID если Вы внутри WordPress цикла и у Вас объявлена глобальная переменная $post
echo esc_url( $your_post_type_name->display('link') );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработал первый вариант, только без `usc_url` а просто   `<?php echo  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'link', true ) ; ?>`

Comment: @Павел там должно быть [esc_url()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/esc_url) -- это функция для очистки URL которая изменяет неправильные и удаляет опасные символы. Прошу прощения, опечатался, поправил. Да, без нее тоже будет работать